# How to provide a MODULE.bazel file to local_path_override?

Tags: bazel, bzlmod

I search for a way to provide a `MODULE.bazel` file to `local_path_override`.

Example:

*MODULE.bazel*:

```
bazel_dep(name = "fmt", version = "10.1.1")

local_path_override(
    module_name = "fmt",
    # Local copy of https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt at some newer commit as 10.1.1
    # Does not have a MODULE.bazel file
    path = "../third_party/fmt",
)
```

What I actually want to do is something like this:

```
bazel_dep(name = "fmt", version = "10.1.1")

local_path_override(
    module_name = "fmt",
    module_file = "//:fmt.MODULE.bazel", # provide a MODULE.bazel file here
    # Local copy of https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt at some newer commit as 10.1.1
    # Does not have a MODULE.bazel file
    path = "../third_party/fmt",
)
```

I want to provide a `MODULE.bazel` from outside, since the local copy does not have one. Please note that the attribute `module_file` does not exist and was just an idea how I could imagine how this could work.

Using a WORKSPACE approach it worked this way:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "fmt",
    build_file = "//:fmt.BUILD",
    path = "../third_party/fmt",
)
```

I search for something similar in the Bzlmod world.

I was also thinking if I could use `archive_override` providing the `MODULE.bazel` file as a patch. It seems that `archive_override` can handle `file://` URLs, but as for as I understand this does not work with relative path names (such as `../third_party/fmt`) and would require me to define an absolute system specific path.

BTW: I am using Bazel 6.3.2

Comment: `local_path_override` expects you've setup the tree for bzlmod an point bazel to it. Hence, when you locally deploy this tree, also dump corresponding `MODULE.bazel` in it. Not sure what would be the point of adding this specific bit at a later point / on the fly, or from a different tree in the first place?

Comment: @OndrejK. Some motivation as using `new_local_repository` - we could also live only with `local_repository` but sometime it is more convenient to provide it on the fly...

Comment: I mean essentially (and foreseen use case would seem to be)... when you create the (local) tree, also include the `MODULE.bazel`. By its nature, I am not sure `*_override` is meaningful for "permanent" setup / way to deploy things. You could also have a local registry (and storage)... handle URL setup with deployment script. But essentially if you want to collect deps from arbitrary stuff locally deployed on the host when building a project, not sure bzlmod isn't just unnecessary complication and you would not be better served with "legacy" / workspace external dependencies?

Comment: What I am trying to say: you need to take some action(s) (download+explode; `git clone`, ...) for the local tree storing module content to exist. It seems entirely doable and reasonable to also deploy corresponding `MODULE.bazel` into the tree at this time as part of the local deployment steps. In fact splitting the module source and declaration seems unnecessarily risky (error prone), it's not like the same tree could / should be `modA-1.0` in one consuming project and `modB-1.2`  or `modA-3.2.1` in other consuming trees (or each time with unique transitive deps).